# What's the name of the process in which a word acquires new meanings?

Tags: terminology, semantics, language-change

I am almost sure there is a proper name for that but I forgot. It would be the opposite of semantic bleaching...

Comment: There's probably at [least nine processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change), depending on who is categorising them!

Answer (score 3):

You could be referring to semantic change or more specifically semantic expansion (as described here: https://www.uni-due.de/SHE/SHE_Change_Semantic.htm#types ), depending on what type of change it is, there is then more specific terms.